# How to save and fetch VideoURL in iOS swift using core data?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a videoURL like `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3C80B7F1-F0AA-4723-B7F5-E7AC5E71CA09/Documents/2018-Nov-12%2014:09:01output.mov`

I am saving this videoURL by using below code as converting to DATA.

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Device", in: context)

let newEntity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

self.videoData =  NSData(contentsOf: self.videoURL as URL)! as Data

newEntity.setValue(self.videoData, forKey:"videoURL")

do {

    try context.save()
    print("saved")

} catch {
    print("not saved") 
}
```

but I am unable to converting this data to url while fetching. Could anyone guide me how to do this task?

Comment: Why are you saving `Data` instead of **URL** in the first place !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say but this is wrong. why do you want to convert URL to data? You just save URL as string then fetch this string and work with the URL

Answer (score 2):

You are saving the loaded video data, not the URL.

Set the type of the attribute `videoURL` to `URI` and the type of the corresponding property to `URL` and save `self.videoURL`

By the way, don't use `NS` classes like `NSURL` and `NSData`, use `URL` and `Data` and it's highly recommended to use  dot notation rather than KVC `(value(forKey:)` when accessing `NSManagedObject` properties

```
let newEntity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Device
self.videoData = Data(contentsOf: self.videoURL)! 

newEntity.videoURL = self.videoURL

do { 
    try context.save()
    print("saved")
} catch {
  print(error) 
}
```